# Cassandra - unique constraint on row key

Tags: cassandra

I would like to know whenever it is possible in Cassandra to specify unique constrain on row key. Something similar to SQL Server's `ADD CONSTRAINT myConstrain UNIQUE (ROW_PK)`

In case of insert with already existing row key, the existing data will be not overwritten, but I receive kind of exception or response that update cannot be performed due to constrain violation.

Maybe there is a workaround for this problem - there are counters which updates seams to be atomic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cassandra - a unique constraint can be implemented with the help of a primary key constrain. You need to put all the columns as primary key, those you want to be unique. Cassandra will tackle the rest on it own.

```
CREATE TABLE users (firstname text, lastname text, age int, 
email text, city text, PRIMARY KEY (firstname, lastname));
```

It means Cassandra will not insert two different rows in this `users` table when `firstname` and `lastname` are the same.

Comment: at the time when I've asked this question it was not possible. Thanks for update!

Comment: @MaciejMiklas Note that the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` will still update a row with the same `firstname` and `lastname`. It just won't create a new row with such a `PRIMARY KEY`. So it's not exactly the same as a lock, although it will certainly work as expected in the sense that a `SELECT` + `INSERT` will nearly do what you want (i.e. with two distinct processes, two `INSERT` may happen from two different users...)

Answer (score 17):

Lightweight transactions?

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_ltwt_transaction_c.html

`INSERT INTO customer_account (customerID, customer_email) 
VALUES (‘LauraS’, ‘lauras@gmail.com’)
IF NOT EXISTS;`

Comment: I think this is perfect. There is a good write-up with some more details here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0

Comment: This only works if you want to make sure all of the inserted values are unique, right? It won't work if e.g. another row with the same email but different `customerID` already exists, i.e. it will insert a new row in this case.

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, no, because Cassandra does not perform any checks on writes.  In order to implement something like that, Cassandra would have to do a read before every write, to check whether the write is allowed.  This would greatly slow down writes.  (The whole point is that writes are streamed out sequentially without needing to do any disk seeks -- reads interrupt this pattern and force seeks to occur.)

I can't think of a way that counters would help, either.  Counters are not implemented using an atomic test-and-set.  Instead, they essentially store lots of deltas, which are added together when you read the counter value.

Comment: thank you - this is how I've expected it. Could someone else also confirm that - I would like to be 101% sure :)

Comment: You could of course do a bunch of writes and then check afterwards to see if your constraint was violated. I don't know if that would be helpful to you, though.

Comment: Theodore is correct.  Typically when you want uniqueness, you should use a UUID or some combination of details that will guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: You said cassandra doesnt perform checks on write. What about primary key ? Cassandra must check it before write

Answer (score 4):

I feel good today and I will not downvote all the other posters for saying that it is not even remotely possible to create a lock with just and only a Cassandra cluster. I just implemented the Lamport's bakery algorithm¹ and it works just fine. No need for any other strange thing like zoos, cages, memory tables, etc.

Instead you can implement a poor's man multi-process / multi-computer locking mechanism as long as you can obtain a read and write with at least QUORUM consistency. That's all you really need to be able to properly implement this algorithm. (the QUORUM level can change depending on the type of lock that you need: local, rack, full network.)

My implementation will appear in version 0.4.7 of libQtCassandra (in C++). I already tested and it locks perfectly. There are a few more things I want to test and let you define a set of parameters that right now are hard coded. But the mechanism works perfectly.

When I found this thread I thought that something was wrong. I searched some more and found a page on Apache which I mention below. The page is not very advanced but their MoinMoin does not offer a discussion page... Anyway, I think that it was worth mentioning. Hopefully people will start implementing that locking mechanism in all sorts of languages such as PHP, Ruby, Java, etc. so it gets used and known that it works.

Source: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Locking

¹ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm

The following is more or less the way I implemented my version. This is just a simplified synopsis. I may need to update it some more because I did some enhancements while testing the resulting code (also the real code uses RAII and includes a timeout capability on top of the TTL.) The final version will be found in the [libQtCassandra library](http://snapwebsites.org/project/libqtcassandra).

```
// lock "object_name"
void lock(QString object_name)
{
    QString locks = context->lockTableName();
    QString hosts_key = context->lockHostsKey();
    QString host_name = context->lockHostName();
    int host = table[locks][hosts_key][host_name];
    pid_t pid = getpid();

    // get the next available ticket
    table[locks]["entering::" + object_name][host + "/" + pid] = true;
    int my_ticket(0);
    QCassandraCells tickets(table[locks]["tickets::" + object_name]);
    foreach(tickets as t)
    {
        // we assume that t.name is the column name
        // and t.value is its value
        if(t.value > my_ticket)
        {
            my_ticket = t.value;
        }
    }
    ++my_ticket; // add 1, since we want the next ticket
    table[locks]["tickets::" + object_name][my_ticket + "/" + host + "/" + pid] = 1;
    // not entering anymore, by deleting the cell we also release the row
    // once all the processes are done with that object_name
    table[locks]["entering::" + object_name].dropCell(host + "/" + pid);

    // here we wait on all the other processes still entering at this
    // point; if entering more or less at the same time we cannot
    // guarantee that their ticket number will be larger, it may instead
    // be equal; however, anyone entering later will always have a larger
    // ticket number so we won't have to wait for them they will have to wait
    // on us instead; note that we load the list of "entering" once;
    // then we just check whether the column still exists; it is enough
    QCassandraCells entering(table[locks]["entering::" + object_name]);
    foreach(entering as e)
    {
        while(table[locks]["entering::" + object_name].exists(e))
        {
            sleep();
        }
    }

    // now check whether any other process was there before us, if
    // so sleep a bit and try again; in our case we only need to check
    // for the processes registered for that one lock and not all the
    // processes (which could be 1 million on a large system!);
    // like with the entering vector we really only need to read the
    // list of tickets once and then check when they get deleted
    // (unfortunately we can only do a poll on this one too...);
    // we exit the foreach() loop once our ticket is proved to be the
    // smallest or no more tickets needs to be checked; when ticket
    // numbers are equal, then we use our host numbers, the smaller
    // is picked; when host numbers are equal (two processes on the
    // same host fighting for the lock), then we use the processes
    // pid since these are unique on a system, again the smallest wins.
    tickets = table[locks]["tickets::" + object_name];
    foreach(tickets as t)
    {
        // do we have a smaller ticket?
        // note: the t.host and t.pid come from the column key
        if(t.value > my_ticket
        || (t.value == my_ticket && t.host > host)
        || (t.value == my_ticket && t.host == host && t.pid >= pid))
        {
            // do not wait on larger tickets, just ignore them
            continue;
        }
        // not smaller, wait for the ticket to go away
        while(table[locks]["tickets::" + object_name].exists(t.name))
        {
            sleep();
        }
        // that ticket was released, we may have priority now
        // check the next ticket
    }
}

// unlock "object_name"
void unlock(QString object_name)
{
    // release our ticket
    QString locks = context->lockTableName();
    QString hosts_key = context->lockHostsKey();
    QString host_name = context->lockHostName();
    int host = table[locks][hosts_key][host_name];
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    table[locks]["tickets::" + object_name].dropCell(host + "/" + pid);
}

// sample process using the lock/unlock
void SomeProcess(QString object_name)
{
    while(true)
    {
        [...]
        // non-critical section...
        lock(object_name);
        // The critical section code goes here...
        unlock(object_name);
        // non-critical section...
        [...]
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE (2019/05/05):** Although it was a great exercise to get the Lamport's Bakery implemented using Cassandra, it is an anti-pattern for a Cassandra database. This means it is likely to perform poorly on a heavy load. Since then I created a new [lock system](https://snapwebsites.org/project/snaplock), still using the Lamport's Algorithm, but keeping all of the data in memory (it's very small) and still allowing multiple computers to participate in the lock so if one goes down, the lock system continues to work as expected (many of the other lock systems do not have that capability. When the *master* goes down, you lose your lock capability until another computer decides to itself become the new master...)

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you cannot
In cassandra all your writes are reflected in

1. Commit log
2. Memtable

to scale million writes & durability

If we consider your case. Before doing this cassandra need to

1. Check for existence in Memtable
2. Check for existence in all sstables [If your key is flushed from Memtable]

In the case 2 all though, cassandra has implemented bloom filters it is going to be a overhead. Every write is going to be a read & write

But your request can reduce merge overhead in cassandra because at anytime the key is going to be there in only one sstable. But cassandra's architecture will have to be changed for that.

Jus check this video http://blip.tv/datastax/counters-in-cassandra-5497678 or download this presentation http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/cassandra_sf_counters.pdf to see how counters have come in to cassandra's existence.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use Cages and ZooKeeper:

http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/locking-and-transactions-over-cassandra-using-cages