# Cassandra CQL - Update command to not create new row

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is there any way to prevent the CQL command **Update** from creating a new row if the row key **'row1'** doesn't exist?

```
UPDATE columnfamily SET data = 'test data' WHERE key = 'row1';
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154332/cassandra-unique-constraint-on-row-key/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2015-04-10:**

As of Cassandra 2.0 you can use [light weight transactions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_ltweight_transaction_t.html) to accomplish this. Be aware that although they are called "light weight" these queries require a lot more work to be done on the Cassandra cluster.

Thanks to @BSB for the update.

**Pre 2.0 answer:**

No. Unlike in SQL, in CQL `Update` and `insert` are semantically the same. You would have to do a read first to determine the existence of the row.

Comment: Thanks. I have found that cassandra 1.1 is in beta now and includes CQL version 3. I don't suppose you know if that will contain anything that could resolve this issue?

Comment: There is the concept of lightweight transactions in C*. You can do "UPDATE ... IF EXISTS" or "IF X=Y"