# Questions on Cassandra data types

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra and would like to know about the following:

1. How do I set a default value for a column.
2. How do I define a char data type or at least define a size for varchar something like varchar(100) in mysql.
3. how do I specify if a column can have null values or not.
4. How auto-increment feature can be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I have tried searching a lot on Google but couldn't find any answers. So I believe it is not supported in Cassandra but need confirmation from an expert.

Answer (score 2):

> Default Value for a column & Column can null values or not

These two features makes sense in relational model where proper schema is a must. But cassandra is originally built for schema less architecture [this doesn't mean that you can't use it for a data model with proper schema]. Although column families support [`column_metadata`](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/ddl/column_family#static-column-families) it is just a relaxed constraint.

> In static column families, although the rows generally have the same set of columns, they are not
>   required to have all of the columns defined

Refered from the same doc

> How do I define a char data type or at least define a size for varchar
>   something like varchar(100)

Cassandra by default has [`ascii & uft8`](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/ddl/column_family#about-data-types-comparators-and-validators) type

> How auto-increment feature can be done

Requirement is same as [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154332/cassandra-unique-constraint-on-row-key). Direct answer is no.

Comment: @Srinidhi don't forget to accept responses that answer your question